# Customising jQuery Datepicker Next Button Behaviour

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm working on an airline reservations system and we use a heavily customised jQuery Datepicker to show the dates we fly a given route.  The latest requirement is for a custom jump when the user clicks 'Next Month', that is if there are no flights (no days set selectable via the beforeShowDay callback) in that month, the calendar will jump to the month with the next available flights.   Something like:

```
 function handleMonthYearChange(year, month, inst){
    // look-up month with next available flights - say two months from now.
    // get the dpInstance, and then force a custom span 
    $.datepicker._adjustDate(dpInstance ,**2**,'M'); 
}
```

I thought for a moment I'd be able to assign my own value to the month parameter and just let the function return.  No such luck

All the code that does the setSelectable logic when the calendar loads is written and live.
I need to be able to catch these UI clicks on Prev and Next, do my 'Next FLights' look-up and then jump to the next month with selectable dates.

Any suggestions much appreciated

Mark

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  In fact I'm getting somewhere with this using the built in onMonthYearChange event and setting the default date for the datepicker.

`code`                                                           
    var dateOfNextFlight = getNextFlightDate();
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', dateOfNextFlight);
    $(this).datepicker('show');`code`

Comment: Not sure what happened to my formatting there :(